# Why I get Estimate Std. in negative when the data I am using never can be negative?

Tags: r, lme4, lmertest

I am running a script to find out differences between songs of birds (comparing different lengths, frequencies and others). I am using linear mixed effects with lme4 package. I get as an outcome of negative Estimate Std. and since (for instance) the length of the song can not be negative, I wonder if anybody could tell me what I am doing wrong. Find details underneath.

I have been looking for errors in my data and different ways to dispose of the data, getting the same results.

This is how I have the data organized:

```
Bird    site    length  freq    
1   FH  2.69    4354    -58.9
1   FH  2.546   4298    -57.3
1   FH  2.043   5303    -53.7
2   FH  4.437   6084    -63.1
11  ML  3.371   4689    -37.1
12  ML  3.706   5470    -39.7
13  ML  4.331   5358    -48.7
13  ML  4.124   4744    -39.8
14  ML  3.802   5805    -42.5
```

This is the full code

```
#1 song lenght####

library("lmerTest") 
model1<-lmer(length~site
             +(1|Bird), 
             data=dframe1)

summary(model1)
anova(model1, test="F")

pdat <- expand.grid (site=c("ML", "SI","FH", "SH"))

detach(package:lmerTest) # 
model1<-lmer(length~site
             +(1|Bird), 
             data=dframe1)

pred <- predictSE(model1, newdata = pdat, re.form = NA,
                  se.fit = T, na.action = na.exclude, 
                  type= "response")
pred

predframe <- data.frame (pdat, pred) ; predframe
predframe

plot(
  NULL
  , xlim = c(0.75,4.25)  # 
  , ylim = c(3,6)
  , axes = F  # 
  , ylab = ""
  , xlab = ""
)  
at.x <- c(1,2,3,4)
at.lab <- c(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 1:nrow(predframe))
{arrows( 
  x0 = at.x[i]
  , y0 = (predframe$fit[i] + predframe$se.fit[i])
  , x1 = at.x[i]
  , y1 = (predframe$fit[i] - predframe$se.fit[i])
  , code = 3  
  , angle = 90  
  , length = 0.12  
  , col = "gray25")
  points(
    x = at.x[i]
    , y = predframe$fit[i]
    , pch = 21
    ,bg="black"
    , col = "black"
    , cex = 1.25)  # point size
}


axis(1, labels = c("Mainland","Sully", "Flat Holm","Skokholm"), at = at.lab)  
axis(2, at = c(3,4,5,6), labels = c(3,4,5,6), las = 1, cex.axis = 1)  
box()  
title(xlab = "Location",  line = 2.5, cex = 0.8)  
title(ylab = expression(paste("song length (secs)")), line = 2.75)
```

Ahead is the first part of the results, not sure why the site FH (siteFH       -0.9480) comes up as negative. This happens with other variables as well, so I guess must be something wrong with the model. I am a beginner, please be considered with me, I've looked already and I haven't found a similar question.

Thank you in advance.

```
Results
`Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1852 -0.4119 -0.0071  0.5304  2.2659 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Bird     (Intercept) 0.51798  0.7197  
 Residual             0.07313  0.2704  
Number of obs: 112, groups:  Bird, 42

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.2429     0.1787 37.6710  23.745  < 2e-16 ***
siteFH       -0.9480     0.2965 36.3879  -3.197 0.002871 ** 
siteSH        1.2641     0.3173 35.4150   3.983 0.000323 ***
siteSI       -0.4258     0.3515 35.2203  -1.212 0.233769    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) siteFH siteSH
siteFH -0.603              
siteSH -0.563  0.339       
siteSI -0.508  0.306  0.286
> anova(model1, test="F")
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
site 3.0075  1.0025     3 35.336  13.709 4.337e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`
```

Comment: What is your error type in this? Are the errors normally distributed?

Comment: As far as your results: the first column is `Estimate` and the second is `Std. Error` and the estimate can be negative if the the `site` is associated with shorter song length (other effects taken into account). Is `site` a factor variable in R? You'll have to interpret the estimates based on what you set / it is using as a reference category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in the output are right aligned, so the column is named **Estimate**, the next column is named **Std. Error**.

The estimate describes the *association* between your dependent and independent variables. It does not describe any values in your dataset.

A negative estimate just means "the larger your dependent variable (`length`), the lower your independent variable (`site`)" (or vice versa). But within this relationship, both variables still can be positive.

In detail, an estimate of -0.948 in your case means that the `length` for `siteFH` is about 0.948 *lower* than the length for `siteML` (the reference category, not shown in the output). However, it *does not* mean that `siteFH` is negative.